# Does license key require internet verification?

Tags: pspdfkit

Do PSPDFKit license keys require the internet to verify before the viewer can be used? Will the license key need to be reverified after a certain period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

License validation happens offline, we will not require internet pings. For more details, see

- https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/faq/sdk-security/#network-access
- https://pspdfkit.com/guides/android/current/announcements/subscription-validation/#how-license-validation-works

In the future, please reach out to our support portal at pspdfkit.com/support/request/ - we're happy to provide support there for our commercial SDK.